# Interweave rows from 2 dfs panda

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have 2 dfs, I want to interweave the rows from these 2 dfs to build 1 df.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SONY': [1,3,5,7,9],}, index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SONY': [2,4,6,8,10],}, index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

Expected output

```
   SONY
a   1
a   2
b   3
b   4
c   5
c   6
d   7
d   8
e   9
e   10
```

My failed attempt, I was thinking of looping over the dfs and extracting the rows and putting them in a list and then building a df from it.

```
dfs=[]
numofrows = len(df.index)
for x in range(0, numofrows):
    dfs.append(pd.concat([df1.iloc[x], df2.iloc[x]], ignore_index=True))
```

Why am I doing this: I'm trying to replicate a df behind a chart and this is what it looks like.

Comment: No sorry, I should've used different items for the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it so the indexes are not the same, then use `zip`, [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
import numpy as np

# Change indices
df1.index+='1'
df2.index+='2'

order = np.hstack(list(zip(df1.index, df2.index)))
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reindex(order)
print(df)
```

[out]

```
    SONY
a1     1
a2     2
b1     3
b2     4
c1     5
c2     6
d1     7
d2     8
e1     9
e2    10
```